# How can i remove the 3rd and last double quote from a nested string using JS (if not possible, how can i do it using Regex)

Tags: javascript, string, double-quotes

I want "data" to still have double quotes but i dont want double quotes wrapping data's value object.
Note, "description" may have have a different number of characters each time.
Finally, this will be used for 100+ items

I have this:

```
{"data": "{"id": 1, "name": "test", "description": "description with variable number of characters"}"}
```

I want this:

```
{"data": {"id": 1, "name": "test", "description": "description with variable number of characters"}}
```

remove the (") wrapping the id, name, description object

Comment: `obj.data = JSON.parse(obj.data)` ?  Though probably won't work as it depends on how your "I have this" is *actually* stored - it's not valid javascript nor json, so it's unclear how you "have this" in the first place.

Comment: How did you create this string? Probably you should fix it there.

Comment: @freedomn-m How could a string not be valid JavaScript? It's probably something like `const str = '{"data": "{"id": 1, "name": "test", "description": "description with variable number of characters"}"}';`

Comment: im receiving a json object {"id": 1, etc} and i need to wrap it in {"data": {"id": 1, etc}}. but when i do it turns the json object into a string.

Comment: JSON is a text format. JSON is always a string. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @jabaa *probably* - but not definitely.  What's *provided* is not a string - it might be meant to be wrapped in `'`, it might not be.  After all, then they say "JSON object" - so they don't know what JSON is.

Comment: The question states _"I have..."_. The only way to have the following line, is a string.

Answer (score -1):

Use `JSON.parse` for parsing JSON data.

```js
const data = `{"data": "{\\"id\\": 1, \\"name\\": \\"test\\", \\"description\\": \\"description with variable number of characters\\"}"}`;

let parsed = JSON.parse(data);
parsed.data = JSON.parse(parsed.data);

const result = JSON.stringify(parsed, null, 2);
console.log(result);
```